# Rails - Encrypted Data Storage with Raw SQL Queries

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, encryption, lockbox-3

I have users table and redemptions Table. So for security reasons we have encrypted our users table email and mobile column.

User Table columns before encryption:

```
id | mobile | email | name |
```

User Table columns after encryption:

```
id | name | email_ciphertext | mobile_ciphertext | email_bidx | mobile_bidx
```

User.rb

```
has_many :redemptions
```

Redemption.rb

belongs_to :User

So In one place I wanted to get Redemption information along with User details. My query before encrypting the User's mobile and email was

```
Redemption.joins(:user).group('users.id, users.mobile').select('users.id AS uid, users.name AS uname, users.email AS uemail, users.mobile AS umobile, count(distinct(redemptions.id)) AS total)
```

So this would give me Users and their redemptions count. Now that I have encrypted my data using [Lockbox](https://github.com/ankane/lockbox) and [BlindIndex](https://github.com/ankane/blind_index) and dropped both email and mobile column from users table, what approach should I follow to achieve the same result for the above query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to get redemption count by user, you can do:

```rb
redemptions_by_user_id = Redemption.joins(:user).group("users.id").distinct.count
```

Then query the user information in a separate query.

```rb
users = User.where(id: redemptions_by_user_id.keys)
```

Then combine them

```rb
users.each do |user|
  puts "#{user.id} #{user.email} #{user.phone} #{redemptions_by_user_id[user.id]}"
end
```